# How to display events in basicWeek on more than one line

Tags: fullcalendar

The title of my event is to long to be entirely displayed. How can I wrapped it on more than one line so I can see the whole title ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of this piece of CSS that the title gets wrapped.

```
.fc-day-grid-event .fc-content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Add the CSS below, after fullcalendar.css:

```
.fc-day-grid-event .fc-content {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q44gga27/)